# Why were cows so Important and preferred as sacrifice over other animals in Bani Israel?

Tags: animals, taamei-mitzvot-reasons, korban

I read a lot about cows used in sacrifice , what is the reason that cows were sacrificed and what was the importance of cows for Bani Israel

Comment: Why do you assume cows more important than the other types of animals sacrificed (sheep, goats, various birds and more)?

Comment: @JNF what "and more"? :)

Comment: @avi was actually meaning מנחות, though not animals

Comment: Lambs were slaughtered far more frequently than bovines were.

Comment: @ShimonbM So ovine>bovine?

Comment: @DoubleAA, indeed! In fact, if you factor into consideration the frequency of libations as compared to the meaty part of the tamid, you might even say that vine > ovine > bovine.

Comment: @ShimonbM Spectacular!

Comment: @ShimonbM, it would seem to me a case could be made that the more common an offering the less special it is. Indeed working off of memory it would suggest bovine offerings were reserved for more significant occasions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 4 basic categories of animals that are used in Sacrifices.

1. Cows
2. Goats
3. Sheep
4. Birds

Goats were used for sacrifices anytime that there is a "Kaparah" or "atonement" related to the sacrifice.  I.e. if the purpose of the sacrifice is to correct some wrong, then a goat is used.

Sheep are used for any sacrifices where the focus is on either the individual or family unit.  It represents a more intimate and personal sacrifice.

Cows were used for any large or communal offerings. Cows being the largest animal, they were offered only when the entire nation was commanded to take part of the sacrifice.

Birds were used for any sacrifice where the poor were to be represented, either because they were required to bring a sacrifice but could not afford to bring a larger animal or for symbolic purposes.

It is also suggested that which animal to bring for the sacrifice is purely practical. The more people involved the more fatty animal you bring. Goats have the toughest and least amount of meat, then sheep, then cows, and birds were available for the poor.

Comment: Birds weren't used only for the poor

Comment: it always represents the poor.

Comment: How about מצורע?

Comment: @JNF Are you asking about before or after they are forced to destroy all their worldly possessions? (limited to that one house or room ofcourse)

Comment: ??? מצורע as well as יולדת gave קינים to bring, nothing to do with financial status.

Comment: Are you saying that babies have greats amount of wealth?

Comment: @JNF It's a good question to ask about how the Metzora and Yoledet relate to the poor. And what those two situations have to do with each other that they are placed next to eachother in the Torah and given the same sacrifice. But it's hard to explain it all in a comment. Our attitude as a society towards those cases and a poor person who offers are to be equated though. And there are other more superficial societal relationships as well.

Comment: There's no relationship between the metzora, the yoledet, the zav(ah) and being poor. Also, birds are brought by the nazirite in the event that s/he becomes impure. That has nothing to do with poverty either. Nice answer though, although a source for any of it would be nice. And you should note that sheep are offered far more frequently than any other type of animal as well, their being used for the tamid.

Answer (score 5):

According to [R' Samson Raphael Hirsch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samson_Raphael_Hirsch), in various places in his commentary on the Torah, the ox, typically used for plowing fields, represents humans' power to do effect change in the world. Thus, any time we sacrifice an ox on God's altar, we're dedicating that power within ourselves to His service.

The first time he brings this up in his commentary is on [Genesis 15:9](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8210#v9), in the story of the "[Covenant of the Pieces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covenant_of_the_pieces)":

> Cattle, שור, בקר, are animals of work, actively working in the service of their master. ... Hence cattle represent the power of action and active usefulness.

Answer (score 4):

Of the various animal sacrifices, a cow (or more often, a bull) was considered the most expensive and often most choice. (Mind you, a pauper who can afford nothing but grain who brings it with meaning is valued over the mogul who thinks he can pay off G-d with a nice bull.)

Sforno discusses it being of the most utility to us, and also that its gestation period is eerily close to that of a human; hence when placing its blood around the altar, we think "how do I make sure my vitality is centered around the service of G-d."

Maimonides does observe that the mammals sacrificed -- cows, sheep, goats -- were deified by various idolatrous cultures (Indian, Egyptian, Babylonian, respectively), so part of this was a rejection of that.

Answer (score 0):

Although many offerings required specific animals, where there were options the relative value of the offering indicated how special it was.  Larger animals, like cows or bulls, were more likely to be brought for communal offerings because of the expense.  However, we learn from the Torah that bigger is not necessarily better.  In the first chapter of Leviticus, animal offerings are discussed as being brought by a "man" (Hebrew: "adom").  But in Leviticus 2:1-2, we read that a "soul" (Hebrew: "nefesh") brings a meal offering.  The Talmud, Menachos 104b, explains that the meal offering is brought by a poor person who can't afford a cow, sheep, goat or even a bird offering. Therefore, by the Torah describing the giver as a "nefesh" it is as if G-d is declaring that He will "consider his act as if he sacrificed his entire soul." Hence, we learn that bigger is not necessarily better; rather an offering is only as good as the intent of the individual bringing it.

Comment: Why 104b and not 110a?

Comment: @DoubleAA the quote comes from 104b, not from 110a.  There R. Yitchak asks the question why the verse says "nefesh" and then the anonymous answer replies as I quoted.  It adds a parable:  "The king's friend prepared a meal for the king. The king knew that his friend was poor, so he requested that he make five kinds of fried foods, in order that the meal will be pleasing."  Why did you think 110b?

Comment: @DoubleAA Did you see my response?

Comment: bruce, sorry just did now will reply after shabbat thanks for pointing it out

Comment: I just thought the Mishna there is a better source for your point.